# Build failing because of error in gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, build.gradle

I'm trying to link firebase to my Android app and get data from a firestore database, but my flutter app on Android Studio won't update when clicking run even though I've updated the code. I click on run and after a while it just stops by itself and nothing changes in the app. It is reflecting an old version of the code.

I've tried closing the emulator and opening it again.
I've tried closing Android Studio and opening it again.
I've read through all the similar questions on StackOverflow but none portrayed my problem exactly.
I tried getting and using the latest versions of all dependencies.

The part I edited in android/app/build-gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

dependencies in android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' //for the google services plugin
}
```

This is the output of the terminal:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use 
registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 79019 > 
65536)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while 
merging dex archives:

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\internship_day1_buttonproject\
build\app\i
ntermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar,
```

....(and this last line repeats itself with increasing index numbers until it 
 reaches the following line)

```
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\internship_day1_buttonproject\
build\app\i 
ntermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\283.jar

The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you see the output `Learn how to resolve this issue at 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try **Enabling Multidex support** in your app.

In `project/app/build.gradle` add

```
defaultConfig{
  ...
  multidexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
dependencies{
  ...
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

If you migrate to androidX use

```
dependencies{
  ...
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would suggest you to update ```classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'``` to ```classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'``` and migrate to androidX

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting what worked with me in case in might help someone else. 
Try:

1. 1. on the top right corner in AS, click "open for editing in Android Studio" and open in new window
2. inside that, click "gradle" on the right bar, if you can't find any folders in it, click the elephant icon. That will execute the gradle task
3. it will take some time, produce an error, related with kotlin version.
4. you will go to AndroidManifest.xml and find and remove "$kotlin-version" and replace it with 1.3.10 or whatever version is mentioned in the error
5. click "try again"
6. now the gradle folders should appear

This was the solution of the gradle problem. As for linking to firebase, try the next steps:

1. while you're still in the same place, two gradle folders should appear; android and app, click android-> android -> Tasks -> android -> signingReport
2. SHA1 will appear in the console, copy it and paste it in the "register app" page in Firebase
3. return to the project window, in the build.gradle in the app level, add two lines, first one is in this place:

```
defaultConfig{
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

second line is in this place:

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

4. proceed with the steps on firebase